# It's possible increase margin of command in integrated terminal on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm interested in increase this padding on PowerShell using on Oh-My-Posh, is possible? I want increase this spacing in red:
[evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwfr0.png)